# transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. error: 18 - Connection has been closed by peer

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the aforementioned exception while trying to do an `SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();`  This is a complex (to me) program that takes a few hours to run before throwing this exception.  I thought it was because there might be connections that aren't being closed, but when I look at the database there's only 1 active connection.  And @@MAX_CONNECTIONS = 32767.

When I look at the SQL logfile it says "A new connection was rejected because the maximum number of connections on Session ID 52 has been reached."

Any other ideas of what might be causing the problem?  This is SQL Server 2008 R2, and I'm accessing the database locally via C#.Net.

Comment: Out of interest does your connection string to the database include `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`?

Comment: Yes, Fred, `MultipleActiveResultsSets` is True

Comment: This means you can have multiple commands active on one connection.  I would start by checking your data readers are being closed properly as soon as they are finished with.

Comment: Any way to tell how many commands are active on the connection?

Comment: 'SELECT  r.session_id, r.request_id, 
        c.connection_id, c.parent_connection_id, c.connect_time, c.net_transport,
        s.HOST_NAME, s.program_name, s.nt_domain, s.login_name,
        s.last_request_start_time, s.last_request_end_time, s.transaction_isolation_level
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests r 
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON r.session_id = s.session_id 
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c ON s.session_id = c.session_id'

More info on it you can find it here: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/multiple-active-result-sets-mars-transactions-and-debugging

Comment: A simple `select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_connections` shows an ever-increasing number, and I have found a couple of `new SqlCommand` statements not wrapped in `using` blocks.  I think if I fix them my leak will be plugged.  Thanks, Fred.

Answer (score 2):

Sure enough, I found one `SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();` that was not in a `using` block or ever being closed.  Now all is well :-).  Thanks, Fred, for the help!

Comment: Yup. I was having the same issue, solved with `reader.Close();`.

Comment: What if we're using EF 6.2?